# How to indent part of line to certain amount?

Tags: environments, indentation, paragraphs

I apologize if this is a basic question, but I'm new to LaTeX and typography in general, and I'm not sure how to articulate my question properly.

I have a document which looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
    \usepackage[margin=0.7in]{geometry}
    \usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

    \newenvironment{question}[1]
    {\par\bfseries#1.\ignorespaces}
    {\par\ignorespacesafterend}

    \newenvironment{answer}
    {\par\leftskip=2.0em\ignorespaces}
    {\par\ignorespacesafterend}
\begin{document}

\begin{question}{1}
Testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing 
Testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing 
Testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing 

Testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing 
Testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing 
\end{question}
\begin{answer}
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum

lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
\end{answer}

\begin{question}{3}
Test test
\end{question}
\begin{answer}
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
\end{answer}

\end{document}
```

[image: broken]

How do I modify my `question` environment so that the very first line after the number is indented to the same level the text inside the `answer` environment is? I don't want the number to be indented, but I do want the line following it (but not subsequent lines) to be indented to the same level as the lorem ipsum text.

As an addendum, I was only able to describe my problem with the help of a picture. What's the proper way to explain it by using words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place the number inside a box of the desired width:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
    \usepackage[margin=0.7in]{geometry}
    \usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\newlength\ansindent
\setlength\ansindent{2em}

    \newenvironment{question}[1]
    {\par\bfseries\makebox[\ansindent][l]{#1.}\ignorespaces}
    {\par\ignorespacesafterend}

    \newenvironment{answer}
    {\par\leftskip=\ansindent}
    {\par\ignorespacesafterend}
\begin{document}

\begin{question}{1}
Testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing 
Testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing 
Testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing 

Testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing 
Testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing testing 
\end{question}
\begin{answer}
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum

lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
\end{answer}

\begin{question}{3}
Test test
\end{question}
\begin{answer}
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
\end{answer}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, almost! Sorry, I didn't explain very clearly. How would I modify parshape so that the line immediately to the right of the number is indented? I want all the lines below the number to be aligned to the left normally.

Comment: @Michael0x2a ah, I see. I updated my answer (no need for `\parshape` now). Please let me know if something like this is what you want.